# Filtering out array elements if element contains specified string by SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have sample data like below, I want to extract the elements which has only names and its completed keys not dep_names and its completed key.

I'm trying something like below,

```
WITH dataset AS 
(
   SELECT '{"name": "Bob Smith",
             "org": "engineering",
             "projects": [{"dep_namename":"project1", "completed":false},{"name":"project2", "completed":false},{"name":"project3", "completed":true}]}'
     AS myblob
)
SELECT filter(json_query(myblob, 'lax $.projects[*]' with array wrapper),x -> x like '%name%')  AS project_name
FROM dataset
```

I'm expecting output like below

```
[
    {"name":"project2", "completed":false},
    {"name":"project3", "completed":true}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `exists` filter directly in the query:

```sql
SELECT json_query(myblob, 'lax $.projects[*]?(exists(@.name))' with array wrapper) AS project_name
FROM dataset;
```

Output:

```
                                 project_name                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"name":"project2","completed":false},{"name":"project3","completed":true}] 
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks Guru!!.. Any idea how the same can be done in Hive/SparkSQL ?

Comment: @PavanAithal was glad to help! About Hive - no, TBH